# Is mutable functor still "valid" to be used

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, mutability

After watching [You don't know const and mutable](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) I am kind of puzzled how to handle `mutable` properly in future.
While I think the case of `const` is pretty much safe, since one would assume physical read-only by default (minus the old *logic* exception), properly handling `mutable` puzzles me.
For example with the new threadsafe-condition the following seems wrong:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    [=]() mutable {n = 10;}();
    return n;
}
```

I would assume, that in this case, `n` would have to be wrapped into a `std::atomic` or the copy of `n` be protected by concurrent writes in another way!?

Comment: Which `n` exactly are you talking about? The variable declared in `main` or the copy in the lambda?

Comment: The new `mutable` condition only applies to explicitly marked objects, in this case the *copy* of `n`.

Comment: The `mutable` for a lambda is a different kind of `mutable` than the one for members. It just means that the member `operator()` is *not* marked as `const`.

Comment: @Xeo Is this explicitly mentioned in C++11 spec?

Comment: Yes, of course. `§5.1.2/5`: "This function call operator is declared `const` (9.3.1) if and only if the *lambda-expression’s parameter-declaration-clause* is not followed by `mutable`."

Comment: @Xeo unless someone can provide a conflicting example I would agree with you.

Comment: @LCIDFire A *"confilcting example"* to the language standard? Most probably not, and if yes, then that's a bug in the implementation!

Answer (score 1):

It may be clearer to you if we wrote the lambda out explicitly:

```
struct mylambda
{
    mylambda(int n) : n(n) {}

    void operator()() /* const <- lambda specified as mutable, operator not const */
    {
        n = 10;
    }

private:
    int n;
};

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    mylambda(n)();
    return n;
}
```

(Side note: you actually have undefined behavior in your example because when your lambda copies `n`, it's reading from an uninitialized variable. I've initialized it here to fix that small error.)

As you can see, you have no mutable members so nothing needs to be changed to be thread-safe (according to the talk). Just a regular member variable that can change through a *non-const* member function; non-const member functions are not assumed to be thread-safe.

I don't know if you can mark the lambda member as `mutable`; if you could, you could be in a position where thread safety is a concern (coupled with a const function call operator). But I don't think it's possible.